# Calculate linear transformation T with basis

Tags: linear-algebra

`A` is matrix with the linear transformation  $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard basis.

\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\ \:1&2&0&0\\ 0&-1&-1&0\\ -2&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}

How do I calculate $\left[T\right]_α^α\:$ with basis α = {(1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,1)} ?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Form the matrix  $B$ whose columns are the basis vectors.  Then conjugate $A$ by that matrix.  That is, your matrix is $B^{-1}AB$.

For starters, $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Then compute $B^{-1}$, so that you can do the matrix multiplication.

The inverse is: $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

After multiplying, I get $\begin{pmatrix}-2&-4&-4&-4\\1&4&5&5\\2&0&-1&-2\\-2&-1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: How do I do that? any details or steps ? using reduced matrice as well ?

Comment: You just need to compute $B^{-1}$.  Then multiply.

Comment: is there any other solution using reduced matrice? 
and you said calculate Inverse B, what is the purpose of α then !!!

Comment: coudl ypu please give steps, cuz I did not understand it !!!

Comment: $B$ has columns consisting in the elements of $\alpha$.  Do you know how to find the inverse of a matrix?

Comment: I do, but I dont understand you, Form the matrix B? how? could you please update your answer and give much details !!!

Comment: Ok.  I'll edit in what $B$ is.  Then you can compute the inverse.

Comment: just give more details, and I will do calculation, like find this by doing this...I would appreciate it

Comment: Check my work.  I think I made a mistake.